# Как отправить форму на почту без серверного обработчика (вся логика должна быть на клиентской стороне)

Tags: javascript

```
<form action=" ">
    <input type="text" name="code" id="code" required placeholder="Введите код подтверждения"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required placeholder="Введите пароль"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Подтвердить">
</form>
```

Форма и код для ее отправки должен быть в одном файле

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться бесплатной библиотекой [SmtpJS](https://www.smtpjs.com/), которая отправит письмо.

Если не хотите светить свой логин/пароль от SMTP, то вначале нужно сгенерировать токен. Вот пример (нажмите "Выполнить код"):

```js
const myForm = $("#myForm");
const email = myForm.find("#email");
const code = myForm.find("#code");
const submit = myForm.find("#submit");
const check = myForm.find("#check");
var generatedCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999).toString();

while (generatedCode.length < 4) {
  generatedCode = '0' + generatedCode;
}

myForm.on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  Email.send({
    SecureToken: "044ea062-2b62-42b6-bfae-ea7875e40dee",
    To: email.val(),
    From: "test@gmail.com",
    Subject: "This is the test!",
    Body: "<h4>Your code:<h4> <h1>" + generatedCode + "</h1>"
  }).then(function(message) {
    email.addClass("hidden");
    submit.addClass("hidden");
    code.removeClass("hidden");
    check.removeClass("hidden");

    if (message === "OK") alert("Check your email!");
    else alert("Some error...");
  });
});

check.on("click", function() {
  alert("Status: " + (code.val() === generatedCode));
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Введите email">
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="code" id="code" placeholder="Введите код подтверждения">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Подтвердить">
  <input id="check" class="hidden" type="button" value="Проверить код">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Здесь используется серверный обработчик, предоставленный разработчиками smtpjs. И они могут читать все отправляемые письма. Я бы постремался это использовать

Comment: то есть я оборачиваю промис в функцию и ее ставлю на событие submit?

Comment: function sendEmail() {
return Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
    Username : "username",
    Password : "password",
    To : 'them@website.com',
    From : "you@isp.com",
    Subject : "This is the subject",
    Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
}

Comment: Да, andreymal правильно подметил - здесь в любом случае используется серверный обработчик. Плюс в том, что вся логика по формированию и отправке письма как Вы и хотели - на клиенте. Самой "доставкой" письма занимается библиотека SmtpJS.

Да, на submit вешаете ф-ию, которая вызовет отправку через Email.send.

Comment: Подскажите подобные обработчики